# home page banner res api magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am trying to get an API for banners in home page to list in my mobile app. Is there is a module for that?

Ex:

```
https://{{magento-host}}/index.php/rest/V1/banners
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

1) you can create your custom Magento extension, where you will be adding banners data and provide your API endpoints to get this data via REST.


http://{{magento-host}}/rest/V1/cmsBlock/:blockId